# simple php page with session

Tags: php, session

I need some help getting started with a PHP page.

What I'm wanting to do is create a single php page that will prompt a user for name and track that person with a session. Once the user enters their name I would like the next page to say something like you are logged in as  would you like to log out?" with a logout button. Once logout button is pressed the user is taken to a page that asked them if they would like to log back. In.

I have the session started, but that's about as far as I can get.

Comment: [`Here`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) and [`here`](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-To-PHP-Sessions.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
This is now a single file:

```
    <?php

    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $_SESSION["account"]=$_POST['user'];
    }

    if(isset($_POST['logout'])){

        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        echo "You have logged out.";
    }

    echo "<form action='' method='POST'>";

    if(empty($_SESSION['account'])){

    echo "<input type='text' name='user'>";
    echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='LOGIN'>";
    }

    else {
    echo "You are logged-in as ".$_SESSION['account']."! <input type='submit' name='logout' value='LOGOUT'>";

    }    

    echo "</form>";

    ?>
```

Comment: That's awesome how would they get combined into the same phpb page?

Comment: Is there a way for the logout page to say "You have logged out click here to log back in," Again thanks for your help.

Comment: Please see updated answer. I think there's no need for a "Click here to log back in". Just a notice of user having logged-out above the login page would be enough.